# Probability Models

Tags: sas

What sort of tests are available in SAS that allow you to figure out what the probability of an event occurring is? And I do mean probability, not odds.

Specifically, I would like to know what is the probability a person might say yes vs. no to a particular type of surgery based on their age or insurance status?

I have tried logistic regression, but it appears to only return odds, and again, I am interested in a statistical test that returns probabilities, not odds.

You would think I could just google, "probability models (or tests) SAS" and get an answer, but strangely enough, I haven't - at least not one that is clear. So here I am.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This isn't a SAS programming question, but a methodology question - which method of analysis should I pick/use. You should post your question on stats.stackexchange.com. Review their posting guidelines to ensure your question meets the rules.

Comment: Thank you. Wasn't aware of that other website.

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting odds from logistic regression. This is how the probability should be calculated.

```
Probability = odds/1+ odds
```